# How to split class into multiple modules in Python?

Tags: python, oop, audio-player

Trying to code a music player in Python (not really convenient ik) just to clarify some concepts of OOP and mainly for fun. I'd like to split the class into multiple modules, in particular methods like play, stop, next etc. Could anyone explain how to do that? Thanks in advance. [Code here](https://github.com/vacexpfleger/improved-disco/blob/main/main.py)

```
class App(tk.Tk):

    NAME = "Improved Disco"
    WIDTH = 700
    HEIGHT = 500
    PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title(App.NAME)
        self.geometry(str(App.WIDTH) + "x" + str(App.HEIGHT))
        # self.minsize(App.WIDTH, App.HEIGHT)
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='music_player.png'))

...

   def add_songs(self):
      ...
   def play(self):
      ...
```

Comment: Despite being a very important and interesting point, you question is in fact very broad. Because it boils down to the general architecture of your program. The key is that a class has to be contained in a single module, but it can often be splitted in different (smaller) classes each in charge os a single concern. Unfortunately there is no one size fit all way. It is the job of an analyst (or of an architect) to *model* the expected behaviour and identify the general structure...

Comment: Hard to say more here except that your desire to split a class into several module is a hint that this class is way to big and should be splitted. So, you should refactor your model.